# Pages: "Spelling and grammar" option disappeared

Tags: language

I am writing a document in French and I can't change the spelling language from English to French. I usually manage to do that (Edit > Spelling and grammar), but it isn't working this time around: The "spelling and grammar" option seems to have been replaced with "spelling", and when I click on "spelling" the window that opens up doesn't allow me to change the language. It only allows me to specify whether I want to check the spelling in the entire document or in the main text body. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Start up Pages on its own and create a new blank document and then go to the Edit menu and see if it is correct, with Spelling and Grammar.  If so, try going to Pages > File > Open and see if your French doc also can be opened and works right.